# Application fails when trying to run through Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, task, scheduler

My application works as follows

1. Double click application
2. Select server to connect to
3. Upon successful connection, load the user's layout file exists (just a XML file in a particular format which dictates number of windows forms, their location, their size, color etc.), load the file and the forms which it indicates.

When I run my application via double clicking, all of this works perfectly.

Now I am trying to automate the application via Windows Task Scheduler. I feed in the arguments of the server to connect to, and user ID. When I run through the task scheduler, I get problems with form loading and modifications of their properties.

Here are some code samples as to which lines fail:

```
ActiveForm.Height = 50;    // fails with NullReferenceException
```

This leads me to believe that the program hasn't finished loading. This line of code is located in the function that responds to the successful connection, as mentioned in step #3.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: Did you try putting this code into ActiveForm's Form.Activated or maybe Form.Load event?

Comment: Probably there is no active form, since you open the program with task manager

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Windows Task Scheduler shouldn't block his UI from showing up, should it? Sid, does your application accept command line arguments and stop showing the UI in that case? Show us how it's scheduled.

Comment: @Alexandru The code of line is inside the "Successful Connection" method. Sorry I forgot to mention that. I specifically need it there.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I don't have anything that prevents the form from loading. By the scheduled do you just mean the windows task scheduler?

It is just C:\...\Manager.exe ServerName UserID.
ServerName = Development currently, and UserID = 1

Comment: @Alexandru - if the Task Scheduler triggers when no user is logged on, then the form cannot be displayed.  Sid, What user does the task scheduler execute the task as?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Good find! I never knew that was possible. I think there is an option in Task Scheduler to "run when the user is not logged on" that he may need to uncheck. Now I'm curious, under what circumstances would that run the application? Does it run if you boot the computer into Windows and are at the start screen? What if you delete the user account?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I am logged in and trying it. It is just under my regular (admin privelages) login